# Swift - Dismiss two controllers wrong order

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have something like this in my Storyboard:
NavigationController -> A -> B -> C
where A, B and C are ViewControllers. I am staying in C where I have variable representing B controller and doing something like this:

```
    controllerB?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Which should dismiss B controller and then C. But when I do this in simulator, I see C controller beeing dismissed first and after it I see B controller for a while before it is dismissed too.
I tried delay like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0)
```

But it is not working either
Can you help me? And is it even possible to dissmiss B before C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call pop twice in a row like you're trying to do, and using timers is fragile and not recommended. (It's a shame the pop methods don't take a completion handler like the modal dismiss methods do.)

Just use `popToViewController(_:animated:)`. Send the message to  `self.navigationController`, and send A as the view controller to pop to.

If A is the root, just use `self.navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated:true)`

Comment: Thank you. It works, I did not know about popToRootViewController method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pop both of them at the same time?
You can write an extension for navigation controller and pop back to a passed in viewcontroller regardless of how many vc's are pushed on top.

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func popBackTo(viewcontroller: UIViewController.Type, animated: Bool) {
        for vc in self.viewControllers {
            if vc.isKind(of: viewcontroller) {
                self.popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
self.navigationController?.popBackTo(viewcontroller: ViewControllerA.self, animated: true)
```

Comment: It is a great idea. Although I used Duncan C's solution because A is actually root controller, I am sure this will be useful for me as well one day.